# How to move an image in a window?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

[image]I'm having trouble figuring out how to move and image to a different place in the window. I read about `BorderLayout` but I'm not sure how to implement it. I want to put the car above the text area, so would I use `BorderLayout.NORTH` in some way?

```
b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        /**
         * Displays the arraylist.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (cars.size()>0){

                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Window.class.getResource("/car.png"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


                for(int i=0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
                    sb.append("Car " + (i+1) + ": " + cars.get(i) + "\n");
                }

                Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14);
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(sb.toString());
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); 
                textArea.setFont(font);
                textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                textArea.setLineWrap(true);
                textArea.setEditable(false);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 100, 125 ));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane, "Inventory", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESS![enter image description here][2]AGE, icon);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No cars in inventory", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You state:

> I'm having trouble figuring out how to move and image to a different place in the window.

You will want to tell us the details of your problem. Where is your image now? What do you want your GUI to look like? Details matter.

> I read about BorderLayout but I'm not sure how to implement it.

What confuses you about the tutorial?

> I wasnt to put the car above the textarea so would I use BorderLayout.NORTH in some way?

Generally you use the BorderLayout constants such as `BorderLayout.NORTH` when adding components to a BorderLayout-using container. By "adding" I mean call the container's `add(...)` method whereby you pass into this method first the component to be added to the container and then the constant telling the BorderLayout layout manager where you want it to be added.

e.g.,

```
JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JLabel label = new JLabel("North Label");
container.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

But again for the details you need to read the tutorial. Links:

- [Java Tutorials Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)
- [BorderLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
- [The main Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: I thought the image was added but i guess not. I edited it in. I want the image to be above the text area but i dont know how i woudl go about it within a dialogue box.

Comment: @Eric: the image should be in your question, not my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The border layout feature is what you want to use IF you want to position the picture in different sections. You can have things like CENTER, NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST, etc.

Here's how you would implement it:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
southPanel.add(PICTUREGOESHERE);
add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

First, you set the layout to Border Layout.
Them you create another JPanel.
You add your component to the JPanel.
You add your JPanel to the Main JFrame.